# Multiple array elements in single slideshow slide?

Tags: jquery, arrays, slideshow, element

I've made a simple slideshow from images in an array. I've search for a way to add elements to each "slide", in addition to the image, but they only pertain to image attributes (title, alt, url, etc.). Is there a way to create classes (for elements other than images, like header text and a content paragraph) in my javascript that can be added to each slide's array (and stylized in css)?

This is my current code:

```
var infoData =[
    'images/image1.jpg',
    'images/image2.jpg',
    'images/image3.jpg',
    'images/image4.jpg',
    'images/image5.jpg',
];

var cnt = infoData.length;

$(function() {
    setInterval (Slider, 3000);
});

function Slider() {
    $('.infoFader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).attr('src', infoData[(infoData.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Right now, the data is pulled via an image tag in my html

```
<img class="infoFader" src="" />
```

I'd like the array to be something like this:

```
{
    'category':"category title",
    'linkurl':"http://www.billiards.com",
    'image':"images/image1.jpg",
    'title':"These are people playing pool",
    'subtitle':"a little more information here",
    'more':[
        {'title':"How to play billiards",'url':"http://www.billiards.com"},
        {'title':"Best pool angles",'url':"http://www.poolangles.com"},
        {'title':"Local pool halls and how to avoid them",'url':"http://www.avoidpoolhalls.com"},
        {'title':"Pool hall of fame",'url':"http://www.halloffame.com"}
    ]
},

{
    'category':"category title",
    'linkurl':"http://www.playingtennis.com",
    'image':"images/image2.jpg",
    'title':"This little boy is playing tennis",
    'subtitle':"more info on tennis here",
    'more':[
        {'title':"associated link", 'url':"http://www.assoc.com"},
        {'title':"item of interest", 'url':"http://www.interesting.com"},
    ]
},
```

Essentially, each slide would have multiple elements that I can stylize (position, color, etc.), based on their class, so the HTML would be...

```
<div class="infoFader"></div>
```

...and contain everything, not just the image. I'm new to this, and I've seen it done in one other slideshow, but I don't understand enough of JS to cut out all the extraneous stuff I don't need and customize it for what I do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your killing yourself here. Since you're already using jQuery use something like [jQuery.Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). You specify the container, and it cycles every first level child in it. Those children can contain whatever you want; Cycle doesn't care.